# Get the inner points which are on a straight line

Tags: c#, linq

The question I'm about to ask might seem a Geometry question at the first glance, but it actually can be solved by using `LINQ`, at least I hope so!

I have 5 points on a straight line two of them are at the ends of the line. How can I select the ones that are in the interior of the line (not at the end points) using `LINQ`?

```
public class Point
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;
}

var listOfPointsOnALine = new List<Point>
{
    new Point { X = 2500, Y = 50 },
    new Point { X = 2540, Y = 112.5 },
    new Point { X = 2580, Y = 175 },
    new Point { X = 2620, Y = 237.5 },
    new Point { X = 2660, Y = 300 },
}
```

So using some `LINQ` on the list above should give me the list below:

```
innerPointsOnALine: {(2540, 112.5), (2580, 175), (2620, 237.5)}
```

1. The points are ordered in the original list
2. The points should be in the same order they appear in the original list (listOfPointsOnALine)

[image]

Comment: @Matt I don't have any clue :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly then I think you are looking for:

```
 var newList = listOfPointsOnALine
                          .Skip(1)
                          .Take(listOfPointsOnALine.Count - 2)
                          .ToList();
```

*You may have to check for length of list before doing this.*

Comment: Thanks Habib, I'm always surprised how `LINQ` has such simple answers for questions like this.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault, yes "The points are ordered in the original list"

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Yes, the points are on a line by default. I just realized that I simply could solve this using an index! epic fail! I really need to go get some sleep :DD

Comment: Whoops! I need to go get some sleep too, totally missed that part in OP, sorry Habib.